# How to pass variables from PHP to Flash (ActionScript 3)

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, variables

I need to select game's number from MySql database and pass It to Flash game (ActionScript 3).

For now I have AS3 code:

```
function getVars(e:Event):void{
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("top.php");
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getVarComplete);
}

function getVarComplete(e:Event):void{
    var gameNr.text = e.target.data;
}
```

And here is PHP code (I don't know how selected row pass to variable and send It to flash)

```
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");

$query = "SELECT GameNr 
          FROM   Game 
          WHERE FBId = '". mysql_real_escape_string($id) ."' 
          ORDER BY PlayTime DESC LIMIT 1";
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If I use following PHP:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $id = $_SESSION['id']; 

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","xx","xx","xx");

    $query = "SELECT GameNr 
              FROM   Game 
              WHERE FBId = '". mysql_real_escape_string($id) ."'              
              ORDER BY PlayTime DESC LIMIT 1";
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} 

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo $row["GameNr"];
        }       
        $result->free();
    }
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

`www.myhost.com/top.php` returning correct value `NA==`

---

If I use following AS3 code:

```
function onVarsLoaded(e:Event) {
    var msg:String = "Communication with the server was successful.\n\n";
    msg += "foo -> "+e.target.vars.foo+"\n";
    trace(msg);
}
```

It returning me: `foo -> undefined`

If I change this

`msg += "foo -> "+e.target.vars.foo+"\n";` to

`msg += "foo -> "+e.target.vars+"\n";`

It returning me incorrect value: `foo -> NA=%3D`

Comment: This could help, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633161/as3-php-variables

Comment: Also this might help you out https://php.net/http_build_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

AS3:

```
import net.kaegi.loaders.VarLoader;
var vl:VarLoader;

sendBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sendBtnHandler);
function sendBtnHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    // Variables sent by POST-Method:
    var varObj:Object = {};
    varObj.textinput0 = escape(textinput0.text);
    varObj.textinput1 = escape(textinput1.text);

    vl = new VarLoader("http://yourserver.com/landing.php?foo=foo", varObj);
    vl.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onVarsLoaded);
    vl.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onVarsCancel);
}

function onVarsLoaded(e:Event) {
    var msg:String = "Communication with the server was successful.\n\n";
    msg += "foo -> "+e.target.vars.foo+"\n";
    tf_servermsg.textColor = 0x009900;
    tf_servermsg.text = msg;
}

function onVarsCancel(e:Event) {
    tf_servermsg.textColor = 0x990000;
    tf_servermsg.text = e.target.errormsg;
}
```

PHP

```
// handle coming get
$foo = $_GET["foo"];

// handle coming post from flash
$textinput0 = $_POST["textinput0"];
$textinput1 = $_POST["textinput1"];

// send it to flash
$yourdata = "hello world"; // your mysql data here


echo $yourdata;
```

Comment: here's the library and full code: http://blog.turtlebite.com/wp-content/data/varloader/varloader.zip

Comment: So I need to pass `$row['GameNr']` variable to Flash. So I need to use `$foo = $row['GameNr']`?

Comment: Use `echo $row['GameNr'] in your PHP`

Answer (score 1):

PHP code in addition to your code

```
 $mysqli->real_query($query);
 $res = $mysqli->use_result();
 while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row['GameNr'];
}
```

Please check in format the data is required from PHP script. currently the php code will give you result of `GameNr` as text.

Hope it helps!